# Setting UITableView headers from NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` which is fetching objects from a `NSManagedObjectContext`. I'm using the results to populate a UITableView.

I'm filtering with these two sort descriptors.

```
NSSortDescriptor *lastOpened = 
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastOpened" ascending:NO];

NSSortDescriptor *titleDescriptor = 
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
```

And when I create the `NSFetchedResultsController`, I sort the sections via `sectionNameKeyPath:@"lastOpened"`.

Right now my sections display the standard format like **2009-07-02 20:51:27 -0400** and since no two can be opened at the same time, they are all unique. I need them to cover range of date/times, such as an entire day, and be in a human-readable form. Something like *Thursday, July 2*.

*Thanks!*

---

**Edit:**

This is all inside a `UITableViewController`. Here's some more code.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Display the dates as section headings.
    return [[[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Comment: Are you using bindings to populate the table or have you written a datasource for the UITableView?

Comment: The questioner is developing for the iPhone, so it can't be Bindings, as that doesn't exist in Cocoa Touch. http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/PortingfromCocoa/PortingfromCocoa.html

Comment: You should be filtering out the results by setting `NSPredicates` to your Fetched results controller, btw. You can still sort more than one way, but if you only want to show certain objects where certain "properties are true" (ie a predicate is met) then use NSPredicates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up adding a new property `day` to my `NSManagedObject` subclass to get a formatted date string.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString * day;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter
```

Sythesize the dateFomatter.
 @synthesize dateFormatter;

I initialize the date formatter in awakeFromFetch and awakeFromInsert.

```
self.dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

The accessor for `day`.

```
- (NSString *)day {
  NSDate *date = self.startDate;
  return [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

I then set my section name keypath to look at `day`; you shouldn't need to make any changes to your sort descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to dig into that area of the SDK yet (my work is with C#, so the iPhone stuff is in my hobby time), but from what I can tell you would want to use the other init, specifically initWithKey:ascending:selector: and for the selector you could pass a selector to your compare method that would only compare on the Year/Month/Day, ignoring time.

Here's the url for reference: [iPhone Library Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001921-BAJIDAFH)

Hope this helps!