# How to use NSFetchedResultsController to generate sections after dates

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am presenting a list of managed objects where each has a timeStamp property. I want to sort the list chronologically using the timeStamp property which i do with a NSSortDescriptor. But I also want to generate sections based on whole dates (one section for every day)

The following will give me one section based on second-differences which is too many sections:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"timeStamp" cacheName:@"PatientDetailViewCache"];
```

Is there a way to generate sections from the timeStamp property with the NSFetchedResultsController that are formatted like yy-MM-dd?

Thanks for any help

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is on your subclassed NSManagedObject create a property for a formatted date and sort using that property. There are many questions on SO with similar questions.

[Setting UITableView headers from NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077419/setting-uitableview-headers-from-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

[A NSFetchedResultsController with date as sectionNameKeyPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418703/a-nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-date-as-sectionnamekeypath)

But create a class wide NSDateFormater in the `awakeFromFetch:` like so:

```
-(void)awakeFromFetch{
    dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd"];
    [super awakeFromFetch];
}
```

then in the accessor for that class property do something like this:

```
-(NSString*)myprop{
    if(myprop==nil){
        myprop = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self.OTHERDATE];
    }
    return myprop;
}
```

Then your fetched results controller is:

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"myprop" cacheName:@"PatientDetailViewCache"];
```

Then it will return the formatted date and sort based on that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Played around with it a little and i guess a similar way would be to create a NSString attribute and set the formatted date to it. That way I don't have to create a subclass. Thanks a lot for your help and for the links.